# In android is there any way to know when process died?

Tags: android, process

When my application runs for long time, its process gets killed while running by itself and shows WIN DEATH. After a while, the process restarts again. 
Is there any way to determine when the process died and I can perform certain task

Comment: Ask your device if it plains funerals

Comment: No.  There is no guaranteed call back.  Save your data at the point it is changed and use `onPause()` in activities to save activity state.

Comment: Thanks Samoth for your idea :D

Comment: Hi Simon , actually OnPause() method too doesn't get called. :-|